# Optimizing Cobbs-Douglas given output

Tags: cobb-douglas

I am trying to find **L$^*$** and **K$^*$** (Labour and Capital respectively) given the following:

> Q = $K^{1/4}$ $L^{3/4}$ where Q = 120, w=$24, and r=$128 (Not sure if you need w and r)

I know that if I can find either **L$^*$** or **K$^*$**, I can find the other one easily.

I have found several questions relating to Cobbs-Douglas on here, but none where Q is given. A close example is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/997041/finding-the-optimal-combination-for-the-cobb-douglas-function-given-a-budget), but I don't have a budget constraint.

Comment: You can have tidy upper indices by putting whatever you want to have in the upper index in {} brackets. For example
"K^{\frac{1}{4}}".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is basically to derive the cost function of a firm. What you need to do is minimize costs given the output. That is
$$
\min\limits_{K,L} w \cdot L + r \cdot K
$$
subject to
$$
K^{\frac{1}{4}} \cdot L^{\frac{3}{4}} = Q = 120.
$$
You can solve this using Lagrange or the implicit function theorem (similar application as the MRS).